# I'm new to coding and i was trying to make a discord bot but im getting error

Tags: python, discord, bots

(Error is bellow)

I'm bad at coding at i was trying to make a discord bot but i keep getting this error.
anyone know how to fix this?

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
 print ("Bot is online")

bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.messege.delete()
  await ctx.send("Hello!")


token(notshowingtoken)
bot.run(token)


The error im getting is


```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="d!")
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```


Bot send messege after typing !test`
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well made video on how to set up a chat bot

https://youtu.be/1yLfjMtsV9s

Answer (score 0):

A lot of modern tutorials are outdated.
I had the same problem.

This should fix it:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents= discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
 print ("Bot is online")

bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.messege.delete()
  await ctx.send("Hello!")


token(notshowingtoken)
bot.run(token)
```